Set union homomorphic hash function that ignores duplicates
Does a hash function with set(not multi-set) union homomorphism exist? LT-hash is very close to what I am looking for where items could be added/removed from the set in arbitrary order but adding the same item twice changes the hash(and so does removing an item that was never added to the set).
Instead I am looking for hashing scheme that has all the properties of LT hash and that guarantees either that adding an item that has already been added to the hash doesn't change it H(A, A) == H(A) or allows me to check whether the item exists in the hash so I don't have to add it again(or remove it if it doesn't even exist).
A scheme that works is one where we assign a prime number to each item. Items are added to the set by multiplying the hash of the set(empty set contains a 1) with the prime number of the item and items are only added if the prime number to be added doesn't divide the hash but this scheme is not scalable as I expect billions of elements in the set. Cuckoo filters are another data structure I can use for efficient set membership and to insert/delete items but they require too much space for a set with billions of items. Can we do better?
I see cryptographic accumulators are an option but they seem too heavy for what I am looking for and they require witnesses to be stored and presented to verify set membership. I don't need cryptographically secure schemes and I want to keep the size of the hash within a couple of KBs. Any ideas?
